# If my wheel bearings are freshly replaced, what could still be causing a loud whining sound?

Tags: troubleshooting, noise, wheel-bearing

Once I drive for 50 miles or more, I begin to hear a loud whining sound. I took it to the shop, they said my wheel bearings were worn out. They replaced the bearings on the wheel. I got my car, took another trip, still heard the loud whine after ~50 miles of driving. I took my car back to the shop, they replaced the set of wheel bearings on the other wheel. Now I've been driving 50 miles, and I hear this sound again.

If you've ever wound a hand-crank charged flashlight, its exactly like that sound. Identical. The faster you wind, the louder the whine sound gets. And then it continues for a moment because the spinning part inside is spinning for a second or two after you stop cranking it.

Well that's exactly what happens when I push the gas pedal on my car, but only after driving a long distance.

Are these details enough for someone to know what component of my car is having a problem?

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks for the advice, ill follow it on both counts. And sorry, I shouldve included my model, a Nissan Altima 07. No modifications from the standard engine.

Comment: AFAICT, no stock Altima has a turbo, so that's out. The first thing to do is determine whether the sound is coming from the engine itself or the drivetrain. Once it starts happening, does it continue to happen if you come to a stop and rev the engine in neutral? Or is the pitch always related directly to the speed of the car?

Comment: @DaveTweed It's directly tied to acceleration / torque. I can go 70, not hear it, then when I accelerate I hear it. Any acceleration after a long period of driving. Oh if I rev in neautral? Sorry I misread, Ill have to test that.

Comment: Whining is not really a wheel bearing noise.  Sounds silly, but have you turned the radio on and off?  The noise you describe sounds like a bad alternator leaking AC noise into the radio/speaker system.  The radio doesn't necessarily even have to be on.

Comment: Along lines of above comment, do you happen to have a 1/8" audio cable hooked up to a cell phone? Those things act like little antennas when the cell phone audio output is powered down or disconnected, even with a perfectly healthy vehicle. Make sure the sound is actually coming from outside the vehicle.

Comment: @JasonC no. It's only after driving 50 miles or further that the sound occurs. My aux cord is always plugged in. I also desceibed in detail that the sound is directly tied to my acceleration. If it was an aux cord that wouldnt be the case.

Comment: @SteveRacer It only makes the sound once Ive been driving 50 miles or further. It's also only loud enough to notice when I rev the engine. As in, the more I push the pedal, the louder the whine gets. That doesnt sound like something that would have anything to do with my radio.

Comment: @Viziionary The pitch of the line noise from my aux cable is directly tied to my engine's current RPMs. The volume isn't, though, but line noise is weird so it doesn't quite rule it out on its own. But you've observed it's not line noise, so that totally rules that out of course!

Comment: @DaveTweed Ive just been waiting for a chance to test it in idle, havent driven far enough since you asked to get the whine. But I can say its not only related to the speed of the car: i can drive for an hour at 80 mph, rev the engine above 80mph and still get no whine. Its only after an hour, maybe 70-100 miles actually, that the whine starts. Whether it happens at low speeds or neutral, I havent had an opportunity to test yet.

Comment: Sounds like it has to do with *load*, and the ignition noise is being "rendered" by the radio as a listenting device, not as the source.  @Jason C is right on, as the "antenna" effect from an aux cord can make the problem worse.  You might need spark plug wires (if you have them), or at the very least turn the radio on and off, and remove the aux jack while driving to see if this changing anything.  How hard is that?  Again, the radio isn't *causing* it, but may serve as the amplifier that allows you to hear it.

Comment: @JasonC well to be specific, I havent had an opportunity to test your theory fully yet. I havent driven more than 50 miles at a time yet. When I do drive 75-100 miles at once and get the sound again, Ill test removing the aux cord, turning off the radio, etc.

Comment: @SteveRacer Ok I'll test it. Thanks for the advice. See my previous comment to Jason, much of that is pertinent to your suggestion, and testing it.

Comment: Your most important test, if the radio test fails, will be the test described in earlier comments: Once you drive long enough for this to start happening, pull over, put the car in neutral, and rev it up. Concentrate on performing this test. This is the first good divide-and-conquer style approach that will help narrow it down to what side of the transmission the cause is on. If you hear it when in neutral you know it is not on the drive side (wheels, etc.) -- if you don't hear it in neutral that doesn't necessarily rule anything out but it's still really helpful info.

Comment: Oh, also check to see if it has anything to do with your A/C being on or not.

Comment: @JasonC Tested! Absolutely no sound while stopped, revving in neutral other than typical engine sound. Also tested turning off radio while making the sound, removing aux cord too - they seem to have zero effect. The sound continues once I keep driving.

Comment: @SteveRacer see previous comment

Comment: @Viziionary The sound; you say it gets louder. Which of the following is the volume most closely tied to: 1. The speed of the vehicle, 2. The speed of the engine (regardless of what gear you're in), 3. How far in you have the gas pedal pressed, or 4. The amount of "work" the engine is doing, which is kinda like #3, but maybe more of a feeling and harder to put your finger on. Also is it an automatic or a manual?

Comment: @JasonC Automatic. It's most closely tied to how far I have the gas pedal pushed. I say that because the sound seems about the same when the engine is doing less work. For example, I hear it on the interstate at 80mph. I exit and stop to perform the neutral tests as requested, and then I continue on a road at a lower speed, hear it as I accelerate to 50mph, then rev to 55 to see how it sounds. Reving from 50 to 55 it sounds about the same as reving from 80 to 85. And the sound slowly dies away after 5 minutes of being off the interstate / driving slower.

Comment: @JasonC so work being done is a factor, since it only happens while the engine has been doing alot of work for about 2 hours straight. And to clarify further, the sound is an immediate effect from pressing the gas. For example if I press the pedal hard for 1 second, the sound peaks at the furthest the pedal is pushed, then dies away during the next 2 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 07 Altimas (the automatics) have a CVT that seems infamously noisy from [cursory research](https://www.google.com/search?q=2007%20nissan%20altima%20making%20whining%20noise).

Is it like the noise you hear around 30 seconds into https://youtu.be/WblGvAPPGX4?t=30? It's tough to hear over him talking but you can hear it "winding down" in the background when he pulls his foot off the pedal.

Apparently there are a lot of complaints of transmission noise and issues in the circa '07 Altimas.

In fact, Nissan seems to have released a service bulletin on 4th gen Altima about transmission noise, which seems to state that it's more of an annoyance than a problem. From http://x.nissanhelp.com/forums/Knowledgebase.html?linkid=3069&catid=400:

> 2007-2009 NISSAN ALTIMA SEDAN, 2008-2009 ALTIMA COUPE; WHINE NOISE FROM CVT AT HIGHWAY SPEEDS
>
> A whine or grind type noise heard during acceleration and / or constant highway speeds.
>
> The level of noise may increase as vehicle speed increases. 
> AND
> There are no other drivability issues or stored DTCs related to the CVT.

Also you *might* even still be under warranty. Apparently [Nissan extended the powertrain warranty](http://www.nissanassist.com/faqs.php?menu=3) to 10 years / 120,000 miles, so if you haven't hit 120k yet and it looks like a transmission issue talk to the dealer about a warranty replacement, even if the sound isn't causing a drivability problem because, hey, free transmission.

So, maybe this is the cause. It sure sounds like your description. I would take it to a dealer to get it checked out, and possibly draw attention to the service bulletin, rather than a third-party shop.

Comment: Sounds exactly right.

Answer (score 5):

Fist thing is to check that the bearings have been  torqued properly, over tightening is easy to do and a common problem on newly replaced bearings.

Also if one  bearing goes  it is sensible to replace the other side at the same time. It is also very easy to get grit in the bearing grease whcih can cause very early failure.

Equally it could something entirely separate. engines have a lot of ancillary party with high rotary speeds especially belt driven pumps for oils, coolant and air conditioning.

Typically a failed wheel bearing will be noticeable louder on cornering, especially on the loaded side (ie right side bearing on a left hand corner).